# How to link to open a folder in RShiny

Tags: html, r, file, shiny

I wanted to use an actionButton to link to open a folder on a new tab in my shiny app.

I used "file:" tag to do that but this tag is only opens the folder if the user right clicks on the actionButton and selects "open in new tab", otherwise it does not open the folder.

Here is a demo code showing the method I used:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  uiOutput("OpenFolderUi")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$OpenFolderUi <- renderUI({   
    tags$a(
      href = "file:C:Users/orcunoltulu/Desktop",
      target = "_blank",
      "Open Folder"
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure whether it solves your problem. You can use `shinyFiles` package. Here is the solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  shinyDirButton('dir', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder')
)
server <- function(input, output){
  shinyDirChoose(input, "dir", , root=c(root='your/file/path/'))
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried shinyFiles package but it did not help. What I really need to do is to open the file explorer in Windows and the users can navigate in a specific folder.